# Проблемы с установкой pycrypto

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
pip install pycrypto
Collecting pycrypto
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/60/db/645aa9af249f059cc3a368b118de33889219e0362141e75d4eaf6f80f163/pycrypto-2.6.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pycrypto
  Running setup.py install for pycrypto ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\pythion\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Pythion\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-05vyvq9d\\pycrypto\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Pythion\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-3tiiz8u8\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto
    copying lib\Crypto\pct_warnings.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto
    copying lib\Crypto\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\hashalgo.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\HMAC.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD4.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD5.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\RIPEMD.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA224.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA256.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA384.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA512.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\AES.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC4.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\blockalgo.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\Blowfish.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\CAST.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\DES.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\DES3.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_OAEP.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\XOR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\asn1.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\Counter.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\number.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\py3compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\randpool.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\RFC1751.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\winrandom.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\_number_new.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Util
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\random.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\_UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Random
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\FortunaAccumulator.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\FortunaGenerator.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\SHAd256.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\fallback.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\nt.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\posix.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\rng_base.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\st_common.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\common.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_AES.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_ARC2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_ARC4.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_Blowfish.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_CAST.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_DES.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_DES3.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_pkcs1_15.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_pkcs1_oaep.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_XOR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\common.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_HMAC.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD4.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD5.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_RIPEMD.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA224.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA256.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA384.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA512.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_AllOrNothing.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_chaffing.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_KDF.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_rfc1751.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_DSA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_ElGamal.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_importKey.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_RSA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test_random.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test_rpoolcompat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test__UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_FortunaAccumulator.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_FortunaGenerator.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_SHAd256.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_fallback.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_generic.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_nt.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_posix.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_winrandom.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_asn1.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_Counter.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_number.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_winrandom.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_pkcs1_15.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_pkcs1_pss.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\AllOrNothing.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\Chaffing.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\KDF.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Protocol
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\DSA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\ElGamal.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\pubkey.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_DSA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_RSA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_slowmath.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_PSS.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\Signature\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Signature
    Skipping optional fixer: buffer
    Skipping optional fixer: idioms
    Skipping optional fixer: set_literal
    Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
    running build_ext
    warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
    building 'Crypto.Random.OSRNG.winrandom' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Isrc/ -Isrc/inc-msvc/ -Ic:\users\pythion\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include -Ic:\users\pythion\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" /Tcsrc/winrand.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src/winrand.obj
    winrand.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(27): error C2061: бЁ­в ЄбЁзҐбЄ п ®иЁЎЄ : Ё¤Ґ­вЁдЁЄ в®а "intmax_t"
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(28): error C2061: бЁ­в ЄбЁзҐбЄ п ®иЁЎЄ : Ё¤Ґ­вЁдЁЄ в®а "rem"
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(28): error C2059: бЁ­в ЄбЁзҐбЄ п ®иЁЎЄ : ;
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(29): error C2059: бЁ­в ЄбЁзҐбЄ п ®иЁЎЄ : }
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(31): error C2061: бЁ­в ЄбЁзҐбЄ п ®иЁЎЄ : Ё¤Ґ­вЁдЁЄ в®а "imaxdiv_t"
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(31): error C2059: бЁ­в ЄбЁзҐбЄ п ®иЁЎЄ : ;
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(41): error C2143: бЁ­в ЄбЁзҐбЄ п ®иЁЎЄ : ®вбгвбвўЁҐ "{" ЇҐаҐ¤ "__cdecl"
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(42): error C2146: бЁ­в ЄбЁзҐбЄ п ®иЁЎЄ : ®вбгвбвўЁҐ ")" ЇҐаҐ¤ Ё¤Ґ­вЁдЁЄ в®а®¬ "_Number"
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(42): error C2061: бЁ­в ЄбЁзҐбЄ п ®иЁЎЄ : Ё¤Ґ­вЁдЁЄ в®а "_Number"
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(42): error C2059: бЁ­в ЄбЁзҐбЄ п ®иЁЎЄ : ;
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(43): error C2059: бЁ­в ЄбЁзҐбЄ п ®иЁЎЄ : )
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(46): error C2143: бЁ­в ЄбЁзҐбЄ п ®иЁЎЄ : ®вбгвбвўЁҐ "{" ЇҐаҐ¤ "__cdecl"
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(47): error C2146: бЁ­в ЄбЁзҐбЄ п ®иЁЎЄ : ®вбгвбвўЁҐ ")" ЇҐаҐ¤ Ё¤Ґ­вЁдЁЄ в®а®¬ "_Numerator"
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(47): error C2061: бЁ­в ЄбЁзҐбЄ п ®иЁЎЄ : Ё¤Ґ­вЁдЁЄ в®а "_Numerator"
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(47): error C2059: бЁ­в ЄбЁзҐбЄ п ®иЁЎЄ : ;
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(47): error C2059: бЁ­в ЄбЁзҐбЄ п ®иЁЎЄ : ,
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(49): error C2059: бЁ­в ЄбЁзҐбЄ п ®иЁЎЄ : )
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(51): error C2143: бЁ­в ЄбЁзҐбЄ п ®иЁЎЄ : ®вбгвбвўЁҐ "{" ЇҐаҐ¤ "__cdecl"
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(57): error C2143: бЁ­в ЄбЁзҐбЄ п ®иЁЎЄ : ®вбгвбвўЁҐ "{" ЇҐаҐ¤ "__cdecl"
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(64): error C2143: бЁ­в ЄбЁзҐбЄ п ®иЁЎЄ : ®вбгвбвўЁҐ "{" ЇҐаҐ¤ "__cdecl"
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(70): error C2143: бЁ­в ЄбЁзҐбЄ п ®иЁЎЄ : ®вбгвбвўЁҐ "{" ЇҐаҐ¤ "__cdecl"
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(77): error C2143: бЁ­в ЄбЁзҐбЄ п ®иЁЎЄ : ®вбгвбвўЁҐ "{" ЇҐаҐ¤ "__cdecl"
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(83): error C2143: бЁ­в ЄбЁзҐбЄ п ®иЁЎЄ : ®вбгвбвўЁҐ "{" ЇҐаҐ¤ "__cdecl"
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(90): error C2143: бЁ­в ЄбЁзҐбЄ п ®иЁЎЄ : ®вбгвбвўЁҐ "{" ЇҐаҐ¤ "__cdecl"
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(96): error C2143: бЁ­в ЄбЁзҐбЄ п ®иЁЎЄ : ®вбгвбвўЁҐ "{" ЇҐаҐ¤ "__cdecl"
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\pythion\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Pythion\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-05vyvq9d\\pycrypto\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Pythion\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-3tiiz8u8\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Pythion\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-05vyvq9d\pycrypto\
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте https://pypi.org/project/pycryptodomex/, это форк pycrypto